# How to read multiple values from a line in python when the # of values could change

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have a CSV file where I'm only interested in the first 3 values.  However, whoever wrote the script/program that generated this csv file seems to put additional columns of values and it occurs randomly.  Is there a way to ignore these extra values when reading the file?

This is my snippet of code to process these lines:

```
for line in infile:
    instance, ts, data = line.rstrip().split(',')
    print ("instance = %s, date = %s, ts = %d" %(instance, ts, int(data)))
```

The csv file looks like this.  foo and bar i'm not interested in and they don't show up consistently but I think it messes me up

```
aaa,111111111,500
bbb,222222222,500
ccc,333333333,500,foo,bar
ddd,444444444,600,foo
eee,555555555,600
```

When I run my script, I get a "ValueError: too many values to unpack" message.  I think it's due to the extra random columns/values.  How do I construct my command to read the whole line, get what I need, and discard the extra that shows randomly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using Python 3, use the * operator to collect extra items:

```
for line in infile:
    instance, ts, data, *rest = line.rstrip().split(',')
    print ("instance = %s, date = %s, ts = %d" %(instance, date, ts))
```

Also consider using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) module for handling csv files. Similar to `str.split` csv module will return the rows as list, in Python 2 you use slicing for this:

```
import csv

with open(filename) as infile:
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        instance, ts, data = row[:3]
        # or if row can have even less than 3 items
        # instance, ts, data = row[:3] + [None]*(3 - len(row))
```

Comment: thx for the quick response.  What would I need to do for python2 in case the server I deploy my script to doesn't have python 3?

Answer (score 2):

As you need only the first three values, you can do this:

```
instance, ts, data = line.rstrip().split(',')[:3]
```